# Update existing entry from plugin not saving and producing no error

Tags: plugin-development

So, i'm trying to set a fields content via a plugin on an entry which already exists.

My code is like this:

```
$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);

$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'subTitle' => 'woot'
));

$success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

I get no error and the value of `$success` is `false` but it tells me nothing else.
If I `var_dump($entry)` after the first line, the output shows it has pulled the correct entry.

Comment: I think `setContentFromPost` might be intended for when using forms with `$_POST` data (there are some underlying functions that trigger when using this method) . Have you tried just `$entry->setContent(array())`?

Comment: I tried this: ```$entry->getContent()->subTitle = "woot"``` but didn't try set content! Thanks!

Comment: Do you get anything if you call `$entry->getErrors()` after calling `saveEntry()`?

Comment: @BradBell Aha! There are validation errors, clearly some fields have been made required after the initial entry was saved. Thanks very much Brad!!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `getEntryById`, and this isn't exactly an answer, but here is how I am doing pretty much the same thing:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'mySection');
$criteria->status = null;
$criteria->limit = 1;
$entry = $criteria->first();

...
if ($entry) {
    $entry->setContentFromPost([
        'myFieldHandle' => 'woot'
    ]);

    craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
} else {
    // Could not find entry.
}

...
```

Unless you are setting the page title, then I think you need to use something like:

```
...
$entry->getContent()->title = 'woot';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there were validation failures that were silently failing. The mighty Brad's suggestion of `$entry->getErrors() after calling saveEntry()` let me see what the issue was.

Thanks Brad!